# Remove blur effect that is outside of an ImageView's box

Tags: java, javafx, blur

I'm trying to create a blurred background.

```
<StackPane id="blurLayer">
   <children>
      <ImageView id="blurImage" fitHeight="478.0" fitWidth="328.0">
         <effect>
            <BoxBlur height="10.0" width="10.0" />
         </effect>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

The `ImageView`'s image is updated when needed:

```
SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
params.setFill(Color.web("#242424"));
WritableImage snapshot = gameLayer.snapshot(params, null);
blurImage.setImage(snapshot);
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfB1n.png) is the result. But I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41pF9.png). The blur effect goes out of the `ImageView`'s box. How can I stop it, or crop to its original size?

Comment: What's `gameLayer`? Maybe provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user1803551 That is totally irrelevant... But it's a `StackPane`, with the same size (478x328).